# How to authorize user to access their Spotify API without requiring them to provide their own client id and secret?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to create a program that uses Spotify's API to retrieve a list of a user's saved albums from their profile and have an album chosen at random for them to listen to. For authorization, I'm currently using the Spotipy library for Python to implement an authorization code flow, and my program looks like this:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import random

client_id = ['CLIENT_ID']
client_secret = ['CLIEN_SECRET']

redirect_uri = 'http://google.com/'
scope = 'user-library-read'


def get_album_names(results):
    for item in results['items']:
        album = item['album']
        album_names.append(album['name'])


sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,
                     client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope))
results = sp.current_user_saved_albums()

album_names = []

get_album_names(results)

while results['next']:
    results = sp.next(results)
    get_album_names(results)

for x in range(3):
    random.shuffle(album_names)

list_index = random.randrange(len(album_names) - 1)
album_to_listen_to = album_names[list_index]

print(album_to_listen_to + ' was chosen.')
```

With this, the user is required to create their own app on Spotify's developer page and use their own client id and secret for the program to work. My end goal is to have an "album chooser" website that is hosted off of my Raspberry PI. I don't want the user to have to create their own app on the developer website and paste in their client id and secret; I want them to just have to log in/authorize their Spotify account and have the rest done by me. Is this possible using the Spotipy library, or is there another way I should be approaching this?

Comment: You could do it with Flask ([Example app](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py)), but you'll need to have a [Quota extension](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/quota-modes) before it will work for other users.